# Getting square root value as a result

Tags: python, math

I'm an absolute beginner at python.

```
import math

def bulma(x, y, z, t):
    return math.sqrt((x ** 2) + (y ** 2) - (2 * x * y * z))

def bulucu():
    x = float(input("İlk kenarı giriniz."))
    y = float(input("İkinci kenarı giriniz."))
    t = float(input("Aralarındaki açıyı radyan cinsinden giriniz."))
    z = float(math.cos(math.radians(t)))

    print(float(bulma(x, y, z, t)))

bulucu()
```

Got this code for Law of Cosine.

My question is for example when I enter , 4 , 4 as lenghts and 90 as the angle between them I should get 4sqrt(2) but instead of that I'm getting 5.65685424949238.

I know that 5.65685424949238 = 4sqrt(2) and also I know that I used "float" in `print(float(bulma(x, y, z, t)))`.

Can I get 4sqrt(2) as answer ?

Comment: If you want to deal with symbols, look at sympy. But a mere translation of this code to sympy will not work anyway if what you want is a code that understands that float value 5.65685424949238 "is" 4sqrt(2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General-purpose programming languages do not work that way.  They use the closest internal approximation (stored in binary, reported in decimal) that they can get.  You can't get 4sqrt(2) for this any more than you can get 1/3, or any other non-standard (for the computer) representation.  1/3 cannot be represented exactly in a finite "standard" string in either decimal (0.3333...) or binary (0.01010101...).

There do exist packages to give you approximations in low-base radicals, rational numbers, etc., but you would need to find and import them specifically; the language doesn't natively support them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the print statement to literally say `4sqrt(2)` then no, its very complex write a function to convert your answer to root form, and 99.9% time not worth it.

The float means you are ensuring the type of `bulma(x, y, z, t)`. Floats are floating point decimals.